# An easier way to do cycle in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to do the following work.

```
if not a; then puts a + " is not defined"
if not b; then puts b + " is not defined"
...
if not f; then puts f + " is not defined"
```

I have to input many words in order to do it. Is there an easier way to work it out? For example,

```
for i in %w[a b c d e f] do
  if not i; then puts i + " is not defined"
end
```

I know the code above doesn't work but I still want to know if there is such an easy way to do it.

Comment: If you have so many local variables that manually checking them is cumbersome then your code needs to be refactored. Anything else will be papering over the real problem.

Comment: The question is misleading. It is asking to display falesy local variables given they are all defined, but the printed text mentions whether the variable is defined.

Comment: Use a single hash and store your data as key/value pairs. The road you're going down is madness.

Answer (score 5):

To display falesy local variables assuming that they are all defined:

```
%w[a b c d e f].each{|i| puts "#{i} is not defined" unless eval i}
```

To display undefined local variables:

```
(%i[a b c d e f] - local_variables).each{|i| puts "#{i} is not defined"}
```